# How to clear balloon popup from bash

Tags: ubuntu, bash, script, notifications

I am setting a notification with `notify-send` in a script. The only problem is that when the script is called several times, all the notifications are added to a notification stack and only called one after the other.

Is there a way to clear all notifications on the screen and display the new one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not clear or "dismiss" the [`notify-osd`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=notify-osd&searchon=names&section=all) notifications. You might have better luck using [Zenity](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zenity&searchon=names&section=all) instead; it has [more options](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/zenity.1.html) than [notify-send](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/notify-send.1.html).

You could use the `--timeout` option to dismiss a notification after some number of seconds has passed.

```
zenity --info --timeout=5 --title="Test Notification" --text "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S): My notification"
```

You could also keep a list of process IDs (in an environment variable or file) of previous notifications and send them a `HUP` signal to clear them out before displaying a new notification.

```
i=0
pids=
for x in $(seq 1 5); do
    i=$((i + 1))
    zenity --info --title="Test Multiple Notifications" --text "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S): Notification number $i" &
    pids+="$! "
done
sleep 5
for p in $pids; do kill -HUP $p >/dev/null 2>&1; done
i=$((i + 1))
zenity --info --timeout=2 --title="Test Multiple Notifications" --text "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S): Notification number $i" &
```

Or kill all `zenity` processes before displaying a new notification:

```
killall zenity
zenity --info --title="Test Notifications" --text "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S): My notification" &
```

Or kill certain `zenity` processes before displaying a new notification:

```
ps ho pid,args | grep -i 'zenity.\+--title=test notifications' | sed -e 's/^ *\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/'
zenity --info --title="Test Notifications" --text "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S): My notification" &
```

Comment: It would be unfair if I downvoted this, but you are clearly **wrong**. With regard to notifications, `zenity` has a far **poorer** set of options than [`notify-send`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/en/man1/notify-send.1.html). And it does in no way solve the problem, because it also does not give control over the notifications already sent.

Comment: @jankes: Sorry, I originally answered on my mobile and couldn't really elaborate my answer. Edited my answer to elaborate.

Comment: What you presented are *information dialogs*, not *notifications*. they can be used as a form of substitute, but are of an entirely different nature. To create *notifications* with `zenity`, you need to use the `--notification` option together with `--listen`.

Comment: @DanCruz It's working, but I get this error: "** (zenity:8624): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged."

Answer (score 16):

This is actually feasible using notify-send:

```
notify-send --hint int:transient:1 "Title" "Body"
```

By setting the `transient` hint, the when the notification expires or dismissed, it does not linger around in the notification bar.

Comment: What exactly does this do differently than just invoking the same command without the `--hint int:transient:1` part of the command?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not the best option but here's an alternative: you can simply kill the `notify-osd` process and restart it. Then publish your notification.

```
pkill notify-osd
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd &
notify-send "Hello!"
```

Comment: For me, using xfce, the process was not named `notify-osd` but instead `xfce4-notifyd`, more specifically `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd`.  I could instead do `pkill xfce4-notifyd` and it would kill the existing notification.  The next time notify-send ran, it auto created the xfce4-notifyd process again, so it seemed safe.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this does not seem feasible with notifications set by `notify-send`. Have a look at [the source code of notify-send.c](http://git.gnome.org/browse/libnotify/tree/tools/notify-send.c) - it creates a notification, sets its parameters but does not store any reference to it, anywhere. Instead, it calls `g_object_unref`, which, as I understand from [here](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gobject/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-unref), effectively removes the possibility of external interaction with the message. So, to have advanced management power over the notifications, you'd need to use different tool than `notify-send` (probably a custom application).

---

A possible crude hack to achieve your goal would be a script using [xautomation](http://hoopajoo.net/projects/xautomation.html) tools. You *could* use them to locate the "close" buttons on all the notification pop-ups and simulate a mouse click on each of them. But that's not so easy and certainly not a *neat* solution.